# Python (2.7.13) - I have a string that looks like an array

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trapping an error but cannot extract what I want out of the returned message.
Here's the code:

```
  except purestorage.PureHTTPError as response:
     print "LUN Creation failed:"

     print dir(response)
     print "args:{}".format(response.args)
     print "code:{}".format(response.code)
     print "headers:{}".format(response.headers)
     print "message:{}".format(response.message)
     print "reason:{}".format(response.reason)
     print "rest_version:{}".format(response.rest_version)
     print "target:{}".format(response.target )
     print "text:{}".format(response.text)
```

Here's the output:

```
LUN Creation failed:
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getslice__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__unicode__', '__weakref__', 'args', 'code', 'headers', 'message', 'reason', 'rest_version', 'target', 'text']
args:()
code:400
headers:{'Content-Length': '113', 'Set-Cookie': 'session=....; Expires=Wed, 05-Jul-2017 16:28:26 GMT; HttpOnly; Path=/', 'Server': 'nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Date': 'Wed, 05 Jul 2017 15:58:26 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
message:
reason:BAD REQUEST
rest_version:1.8
target:array1
text:[{"pure_err_key": "err.friendly", "code": 0, "ctx": "lun-name", "pure_err_code": 1, "msg": "Volume already exists."}]
```

I want to pull out `msg` and `pure_err_code` but the `text` isn't a list.
The `[{ ... }]` is confusing me.  The `response.text[0]` is `[` and `response.text['msg']` throws an index error so this is acting like a string (afaIk).

Answer (score 4):

You have [JSON data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). The response headers even tell you this:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```

Use the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to decode this:

```
error_info = json.loads(response.text)
```

`error_info` is then a *list* containing a single dictionary in this case (suggesting there could be 0 or more results). You could loop, or assume that there is always 1 result, at which point you can use `[0]` to extract just that one dictionary

```
print(error_info[0]['pure_err__key'])
print(error_info[0]['msg'])
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `response.text` is a JSON, so first parse it and then access your data:

```
import json

data = json.loads(response.text)
print(data[0]["pure_err_code"])
print(data[0]["msg"])
# etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response is json so something like this will help you:

```
import json

a = '[{"pure_err_key": "err.friendly", "code": 0, "ctx": "lun-name", "pure_err_code": 1, "msg": "Volume already exists."}]'

h = json.loads(a)

print(h[0]['code']) #prints 0
```

Comment: Thanks pyjg - it works.  I guess that's 2 hours of my life I won't get back!